# Saving to %USERPROFILE%

Tags: c++

So im trying to save my file to Documents on the C: Drive. So it allows me to give it someone else and it will save to their documents.

I read up on %USERPROFILE% which is meant to grab C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\

ie mine would be C:\Users\jsmit\ but that doesn't work for me.

```
void savePassword(string stringpassword, string site) {
ofstream out("C:\\Users\\%USERPROFILE%\\Documents\\New folder\\output.txt", ofstream::app); // Here
out << site << ": " << stringpassword << endl; // This is where it saves the password into the text file
out.close(); // Closes file
}
```

It works if i do this:

```
ofstream out("C:\\Users\\jsmit\\Documents\\New folder\\output.txt", ofstream::app);
```

What code would i need to allow me to give it to someone else and it would be able to save to their documents by grabbing the correct file path?

Comment: You're wrong about `%USERPROFILE%`; [it expands to a path, not a username](http://superuser.com/a/571978/64178)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ knows nothing about your OS environment variables.  If you want to get what that variable represents you can use [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) like

```
char * userpath = getenv("USERPROFILE");
std::string path
if (userpath != nullptr)
    path = std::string(userpath) + "\\Documents\\New folder\\output.txt";
else
    std::cout << "No user path";
```

Comment: @NathanOliver tried it but came up with a weird error.  Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Edited to:  std::string path = std::string(getenv("USERPROFILE")) + "\\Documents\\New folder\\output.txt";
 and worked!

Comment: @IVIaximumPower That means `getenv` failed to get find the variable.  Updated the code to show error checking.

Comment: If the variable in question couldn't be found, how is this the working solution?

Comment: Just as a note: If you care about being able to get the correct user documents folder even if a user moves it, then this isn't the way to go. `%USERPROFILE\\Documents` will not point to the correct documents folder (ie: A friend of mine regularly moves his Documents to another disk. This would not return the right folder in this case.) The alternatives however look to require using the windows API to query the path for `CSIDL_PERSONAL` or `FOLDERID_Documents`, which I'm still trying to figure out, and of course this is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard library doesn't do any environment variable replacement, since it's an operating system specific thing.

It's up to you to do it with the help using e.g. [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: i've got no idea what that is. I'm new to c++

Comment: @IVIaximumPower: Then click on the link and find out!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeh i have done, i dont not understand any of it lol. I guess i wont bother trying to do this. didn't know it would that complicated.

Comment: @IVIaximumPower: It's not, you just have to put some thought and study into it. You won't magically pick it up in the mere _six minutes_ that you allotted to the task.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the user profile path on Windows or Linux with C++17 with filesystem.

example:

```
#include <filesystem>
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <objbase.h>
// define a function that does it on windows
std::filesystem::path get_user_profile_path() {
  wchar_t *p;
  if (S_OK != SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, NULL, &p))
    return "";
  std::filesystem::path result = p;
  CoTaskMemFree(p);
  return result;
}
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <cstdlib>
// function that does it on linux
std::filesystem::path get_user_profile_path() {
  std::cout << "getting linux user profile...\n\n\n";
  const char* p = getenv("HOME");
  std::filesystem::path result = p;
  return result;
}
#endif

// call our function
std::string our_user_profile_path = get_user_profile_path().string();

// test the path it recieved
#include <iostream>
std::cout << "Profile Path: " << our_user_profile_path << std::endl;
```

Additional Notes: If you don't have access to C++17, you can use the same filesystem commands with `boost/filesystem`.